# Infinite world floor grid shader

Tags: shaders, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am trying to render an infinite world floor grid, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842755/how-can-i-render-an-infinite-2d-grid-in-glsl).

My project is using SceneKit with Metal Shading Language but the concepts are no doubt similar between GLSL/HLSL.

[Here is an example project](https://github.com/CaptainRedmuff/FloorShader) where I attempt to render a plane as a full screen quad with the grid lines drawn using a fragment shader.

Full shader [code can be found here](https://github.com/CaptainRedmuff/FloorShader/blob/master/FloorShader/Floor.metal).

---

### Grid Rendering

A simple vertex shader sets the position and grid coordinate for the plane:

```
f.position = scn_node.modelViewProjectionTransform * float4(v.position, 1.0);
f.ij = v.position.xy;
```

The fragment shader then determines which color to render the grid or floor:

```
fragment half4 floor_fragment(FragmentIn f [[stage_in]]) {

    float2 fractional  = abs(fract(f.ij; + 0.5));
    float2 partial = fwidth(f.ij;);

    float2 point = smoothstep(-partial, partial, fractional);

    float saturation = 1.0 - saturate(point.x * point.y);

    return half4(mix(backgroundColor.rgb, gridColor.rgb, saturation), 1.0);
}
```

[image: Floor shader applied to plane (cube added to help visualise rotation).]

I then remove any MVP transforms and simply set the vertex position as is in clip space to fill the screen. This does have the intended effect of filling the screen but mangles the grid lines.

```
//inside floor_vertex()
f.position = float4(v.position, 1.0);
f.coordinate = v.position.xy;
```

[image: Floor shader with no view projection transformations]

---

### Ray Casting

As suggested in the comments, the fragment position should be projected into world space and intersected with the floor plane to find a new vector on the plane. I have an `intersect(plane:ray)` method returns a hit with a distance and a point on the plane or otherwise false if the ray is orthogonal to the plane.

It is my understanding that by multiplying the position in clip space with the `inverseViewProjectionTransform` the result will be in camera space. The plane is also converted to camera space with the `modelViewTransform` and I then test my ray against this which appears to work but with incorrect results.

[image: Floor shader with incorrect perspective]

```
fragment half4 floor_fragment(Fragment f [[stage_in]], constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]], constant NodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]]) {
    
    //f.ij is in the vertex position in clip space (-1, -1) to (1, 1)
    
    //convert position into camera space
    float4 position = (scn_frame.inverseViewProjectionTransform * float4(f.ij.x, f.ij.y, 0.0, 1.0));

    //create ray from camera with direction
    Ray ray = Ray { .origin = float3(0.0), .direction = normalize(position.xyz) };
    
    //convert floor plane from world space to camera space
    float3 worldFloor = (scn_node.modelViewTransform * float4(float3(0.0, -5.0, 0.0), 1.0)).xyz;
    
    //hit test ray against floor plane
    Plane plane = Plane { .position = worldFloor, .normal = float3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0) };

    RayHitTest hitTest = intersect(plane, ray);

    if(!hitTest.hit) {
        
        return f.backgroundColor;
    }
    
    //grab xz values to determine floor fragment color
    float2 uv = hitTest.vector.xz;
    
    float2 fractional  = abs(fract(uv + 0.5));
    float2 partial = fwidth(uv);
    
    float2 point = smoothstep(-partial, partial, fractional);
    
    float saturation = 1.0 - saturate(point.x * point.y);
    
    return half4(mix(f.backgroundColor.rgb, f.gridColor.rgb, saturation), 1.0);
}
```

[This video](https://vimeo.com/428003698) shows the final results where you can see that the grid is not correctly aligned with the world axis. The floor plane is positioned at `0.0, -5.0, 0.0` and the rectangle at `0.0, -4.5, 0.0` which should be aligned with each other but this is not the case. It looks to me that the perspective is off as the grid seems much larger than is should be.

Can anyone please point out the obvious mistake(s) I am making?

Comment: You'll need to convert the rendered vertex position to a world-space ray through the camera, then intersect that ray with your floor plane to find its position in space. Note that this can shoot off to infinity when looking at your floor edge-on, so you'll want a plan for that case.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for your response. Would you be able to elaborate on this a little further? I am using orthographic projection so the edge-on intersection is probably not applicable?

Comment: Not applicable? Riddle me this: What is the orthographic projection of a plane, from the perspective of a camera on that plane, looking at a target also on that plane?

Comment: Apologies if I have misunderstood your comment. Thank you for taking the time to reply. In calculating the intersecting ray with the floor plane, I presume that clipping this against the far plane of the camera would be sufficent for dealing with infinite values?

Comment: I made an infinite grid by world space shader in unity can I send the answer?

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali I would like to see this. Any examples would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I used world space shader to draw Infinite grid

sorry I haven't enough time to convert this to glsl but I hope it will help you

first you should draw a square in shader:

[image]

then you can use fraction to repeat the square pattern to make a grid

[image]

it seems good but it isn't infinite!

[image]

to make it infinite you can use world space shader

[image]

nice!

[image]

you can make your own grid

[image]

here's simple glsl shader:
you can tweak it in [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tsjfDh)

```
float size = 5.;

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
    vec2 tiledUV = fract(uv*size);
    vec2 square = abs(tiledUV*2.-1.);
    vec2 sharpSquare = step(0.8,square);
    float result = sharpSquare.x+sharpSquare.y;

    fragColor = vec4(1.0)*result;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Would you be able to comment your DrawGrid method or describe what it is doing? It looks like you have a property in there that is unused.

Comment: @CaptainRedmuff ok I will comment it as soon as possible

Comment: @CaptainRedmuff I edited the answer. is it understandable?

Comment: @CaptainRedmuff I made a glsl shader in shadertoy for you https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tsjfDh